# Using buttons to set form values (Bootstrap/Bootstrap Studio)

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-studio

This is what my form looks like, essentially I want the user to click hazardous or non-hazardous and have it set a value (itemtype) to Haz or NonHaz
Here are my problems:

1. I'm not sure how or where to store the itemtype variable
2. I'm not sure how to allow only one button to be selected (and I don't want to use radio buttons)
   [image: HazNonHaz]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your reason that you don't want to use radio buttons? because radio buttons are the best for your scenario. If it's because of its look, `bootstrap` has a button plugin you can use:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#button-plugin

#### HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>
            Is your item considered Hazardous?
        </h1>
        <p class="lead">
            This includes all liquids, batteries and lighters.
        </p>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input type="radio" name="hazardous-item" value="true" checked />
                Hazardous
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="hazardous-item" value="false" />
                Non Hazardous
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the name for the radio button control "hazardous-item". I don't know what server-side language you use but that name could easily come from a boolean variable. This is how and where you store the variable.

With `bootstrap` button plugin, when you click any of the buttons, it updates the underneath radio buttons as if you're clicking the radio buttons.

To test, you can put this `javascript` on your page:

```
$(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="hazardous-item"]').change(function(){
        console.info($(this).val());
    });
});
```

You can F12 to go to your browser's developer tool to see the selected value.

#### On form post-back

When you submit the form back to the server, the selected value, which is a boolean, will get binded to the variable, i.e. `hazardous-item=true` or `hazardous-item=false`.

#### Screenshot

[image]

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/230903/

Comment: Quick question David, for some reason it's not showing up in my console when I preview the website, but it works in your fiddle... Any clue what could be happening?

Comment: Followed all of your directions to the tee

Comment: @ecorp: yea and in my fiddle, I was using Bootstrap 4.1.x.